# C++ При завершении программы с использованием ifstring.read при считывании данных с файла выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c++, fstream

Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
_Val было 0x218C0D5E4F8.

Сам файл спокойно считывается и записывается в массивы, но программа не может просто закрыться.
Для интереса решил этот блок кода запихнуть отдельно в условие и именно когда компилятор выходит из него, выдаёт эту ошибку.
Если файл был пустой, то всё нормально.

Проблема с этим блоком :

```
ifstream fSPISOKin;
    fSPISOKin.open("fSPISOK.txt");
    PROGRAMMER temp;
    while (fSPISOKin.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(PROGRAMMER))) {
        ReSize(SPISOK, Null_I, size_programmer, 1); //функция для увеличения размера динамического массива
        SPISOK[size_programmer-1] = temp;
    }
```

Сам код:

```
/*
Необходимо описать структуру с именем PROGRSPISOKMMER, содержащую следующие поля:
- NAME - фамилия, имя;
- DAY - день рождения (массив из трех чисел);
- LANGUAGE – язык программирования;
- TelNumber ¬¬– Телефонный номер;
- Adress – Адрес;
- Email –Электронная почта;
- dolzhnost – Должность;
- status – Статус;
- Project – Проект;
- Group – Группа;
Разработать приложение, выполняющее следующие действия:
- ввод с клавиатуры данных в массив SPISOK, состоящий из восьми элементов типа PROGRAMMER; записи должны быть отсортированы по фамилии в алфавитном порядке;
- фильтрация массива данных по различным критериям любого вида в любом количестве, критерии фильтрации не должны повторяться;
- если таких программистов нет, выводить соответствующее сообщение на экран;
- добавление в базу данных новых сотрудников;
- удаление сотрудников из базы данных.
- изменение параметров;
- вывод сотрудников отсортированным пофамильно в алфавитном порядке;
- запись данных в файл с последующим считыванием.
*/
#define SIZE_PARAMETRS 10
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//Создание структуры параметров фильтрации
struct parametrs_ST {
    int num{0};
    string name;
    bool active = true;
};
parametrs_ST parametrs[SIZE_PARAMETRS];
// Создание структуры PROGRAMMER
class PROGRAMMER {
public:
    string NAME;
    int DAY[3];
    string LANGUAGE;
    string TelNumber;
    string Adress;
    string Email;
    string dolzhnost;
    string status;
    string Project;
    string Group;
};
//Инициализация пустых указателей
PROGRAMMER* Null_P = NULL;
int* Null_I = NULL;
//Процедура для ввода данных
PROGRAMMER Enter() { 
    PROGRAMMER temp;
    std::cout << "Введите имя фамилию программиста" << ": ";
    getline(cin, temp.NAME);
    std::cout << "Введите день рождения программиста (DD MM YYYY): ";
    cin >> temp.DAY[0] >> temp.DAY[1] >> temp.DAY[2];
    cin.ignore();
    std::cout << "Введите язык программиста : ";
    getline(cin, temp.LANGUAGE);
    std::cout << "Введите телефонный номер: ";
    getline(cin, temp.TelNumber);
    std::cout << "Введите Адрес: ";
    getline(cin, temp.Adress);
    std::cout << "Введите Электронную почту: ";
    getline(cin, temp.Email);
    std::cout << "Введите Должность: ";
    getline(cin, temp.dolzhnost);
    std::cout << "Введите Статус сотрудника: ";
    getline(cin, temp.status);
    std::cout << "Введите проект над которым работает сотрудник: ";
    getline(cin, temp.Project);
    std::cout << "Введите Группу сотрудника: ";
    getline(cin, temp.Group);
    std::cout << "\n";
    return temp;
}
//Процедура для присвоению указателю новых значений
void Rewrite(PROGRAMMER*& Main_P,PROGRAMMER* temp,int*&Main_int,int *temp_int,int new_size){
    if (Main_P != NULL) {
        delete[]Main_P;
        Main_P = new PROGRAMMER[new_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
            Main_P[i] = temp[i];
    }
    else {
        delete[]Main_int;
        Main_int = new int[new_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
            Main_int[i] = temp_int[i];
    }
}
//Процедура на изменение размера массива
void ReSize(PROGRAMMER*& Prog,int *&into,int &size_num ,int num) {
    size_num += num; 
    if (Prog == NULL) {
        int* temp_I = new int[size_num];
        if(num>0)
            for (int i = 0; i < size_num - 1; i++)
                temp_I[i] = into[i];
        else
            for (int i = 0; i <= size_num - 1; i++)
                temp_I[i] = into[i];
        Rewrite( Null_P, Null_P,into,temp_I, size_num);
    }
    else {
        PROGRAMMER* temp = new PROGRAMMER[size_num];
        if(num>0)
            for (int i = 0; i < size_num - 1; i++)
                temp[i] = Prog[i];
        else
            for (int i = 0; i <= size_num - 1; i++)
                temp[i] = Prog[i];
        Rewrite(Prog, temp, Null_I, Null_I, size_num);
    }
}
//Процедура для добавления значений в массив
void ADD(PROGRAMMER*& arr,int &size_arr,int num) {
    ReSize(arr,Null_I, size_arr, 1);
    arr[size_arr - 1] = Enter();
}
//Процедура для вывода массива
int *Search(PROGRAMMER*& philtr, int& size, int philtr_num) {
    int *find= new int[1];
    int size_find = 1;
    find[0] = 1;
    switch (philtr_num) {
    case 1: {
        string searchName;
        std::cout << "Введите Имя Фамилию: ";
        getline(cin, searchName);
        // Поиск и вывод по Имени Фамилии
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (searchName == philtr[i].NAME) {
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i;
            }
        break;  }
    case 2: {
        int searchDAY[3]{ 0,0,0 };
        std::cout << "Введите дату рождения: ";
        cin >> searchDAY[0] >> searchDAY[1] >> searchDAY[2];
        cin.ignore();
        // Поиск и вывод программистов с определённой датой рождения
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (searchDAY[0] == philtr[i].DAY[0] && searchDAY[1] == philtr[i].DAY[1] && searchDAY[2] == philtr[i].DAY[2]) {
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i;
            }
        break;  }
    case 3: {
        string searchLanguage;
        std::cout << "Введите язык программирования: ";
        getline(cin, searchLanguage);
        // Поиск и вывод программистов пишущих на определенном языке
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (searchLanguage == philtr[i].LANGUAGE){
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i; }
        break;  }
    case 4: {
        string SearchTelNumber;
        std::cout << "Введите номер телефона: ";
        getline(cin, SearchTelNumber);
        // Поиск и вывод программистов с определённым номером телефона
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (SearchTelNumber == philtr[i].TelNumber) {
            ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
            find[size_find - 1] = i; }
        break;  }
    case 5: {
        string searchAdress;
        std::cout << "Введите адрес: ";
        getline(cin, searchAdress);
        // Поиск и вывод программистов живущих по определенному адресу
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (searchAdress == philtr[i].Adress) {
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i;
            }
        break;  }
    case 6:
    {
        string searchEmail;
        std::cout << "Введите электронную почту: ";
        getline(cin, searchEmail);
        // Поиск и вывод программистов живущих по определенному адресу
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (searchEmail == philtr[i].Email) {
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i;
            }
        break;  }
    case 7: {
        string searchDolzhnost;
        std::cout << "Введите должность: ";
        getline(cin, searchDolzhnost);
        // Поиск и вывод программистов живущих по определенному адресу
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (searchDolzhnost == philtr[i].dolzhnost) {
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i;
            }
        break;  }
    case 8: {
        string searchStatus;
        std::cout << "Введите статус: ";
        getline(cin, searchStatus);
        // Поиск и вывод программистов живущих по определенному адресу
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (searchStatus == philtr[i].status) {
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i;
            }
        break; }
    case 9: {
        string searchProject;
        std::cout << "Введите проект: ";
        getline(cin, searchProject);
        // Поиск и вывод программистов живущих по определенному адресу
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
            if (searchProject == philtr[i].Project) {
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i;
            }
        break;  }
    case 10: {
        string searchGroup;
        std::cout << "Введите группу: ";
        getline(cin, searchGroup);
        // Поиск и вывод программистов живущих по определенному адресу
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (searchGroup == philtr[i].Group) {
                ReSize(Null_P, find, size_find, 1);
                find[size_find - 1] = i;
            }
        break;  }
    }
    find[0] = size_find;
    return find;
}
void Vivod(PROGRAMMER *A,int point_start,int size) {
    for(int i=point_start;i<size+point_start;i++)
        std::cout << '\n' << A[i].NAME << "\n" << A[i].DAY[0] << " " << A[i].DAY[1] << " " << A[i].DAY[2] << "\n" << A[i].LANGUAGE << "\n" << A[i].TelNumber << "\n" << A[i].Adress << "\n" << A[i].Email << "\n" << A[i].dolzhnost << "\n" << A[i].status << "\n" << A[i].Project << "\n" << A[i].Group << "\n" << setfill('-') << setw(30) << "\n";
}
//Процедура фильтрации
void philtrf(PROGRAMMER *&philtr,int &size) {
    PROGRAMMER *temp = new PROGRAMMER[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_PARAMETRS; i++) {
        if(parametrs[i].active==true)
            std::cout << parametrs[i].num << ") " << parametrs[i].name<<endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Введите номер интересующего параметра фильтрации: ";
    int philtr_num;
    cin >> philtr_num;
    cin.ignore();
    parametrs[philtr_num - 1].active = false;
    int new_size = 0;
    int* find=Null_I;
    find = Search(philtr,size,philtr_num);
    for(int i=1;i<find[0];i++)  {
        temp[new_size] = philtr[find[i]];
        new_size++; 
    }
    Rewrite(philtr, temp, Null_I, Null_I, new_size);
    size = new_size;
}

// Функция которая сравнивает 2 программистов по их фамилии
bool compareProgrammers(PROGRAMMER a, PROGRAMMER b) {
    // Разделение имени и фамилии
    string aFirst, aLast, bFirst, bLast;
    size_t spacePosA = a.NAME.find(' ');
    aFirst = a.NAME.substr(0, spacePosA);
    aLast = a.NAME.substr(spacePosA + 1);       
    size_t spacePosB = b.NAME.find(' ');
    bFirst = b.NAME.substr(0, spacePosB);
    bLast = b.NAME.substr(spacePosB + 1);
    // Сравнение фамилий
    return aLast < bLast;
}

int main() {

    int size_programmer = 0;
    PROGRAMMER* SPISOK = new PROGRAMMER[size_programmer];
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    ifstream fSPISOKin;
    fSPISOKin.open("fSPISOK.txt");
    PROGRAMMER temp;
    while (fSPISOKin.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(PROGRAMMER))) {
        ReSize(SPISOK, Null_I, size_programmer, 1);
        SPISOK[size_programmer-1] = temp;
    }
    fSPISOKin.close();
    ofstream fSPISOKout("fSPISOK.txt");

    parametrs[0] = { 1, "Имя Фамилия" };
    parametrs[1] = { 2, "День рождения" };
    parametrs[2] = { 3, "Язык Программирования" };
    parametrs[3] = { 4, "Номер телефона" };
    parametrs[4] = { 5, "Адрес" };
    parametrs[5] = { 6, "Электронная почта" };
    parametrs[6] = { 7, "Должность" };
    parametrs[7] = { 8, "Статус" };
    parametrs[8] = { 9, "Проект" };
    parametrs[9] = { 10, "Группа" };
    int option=0;
    while(option!=6) {
        std::cout << "\n1)Фильтрация\n2)Добавление\n3)Удаление\n4)Вывод\n5)Редактирование(Coming Soon)\n6)Закрытие программы\nВыберите действие: ";
        cin >> option;
        cin.ignore();
        switch (option) {
        //Фильтрация
        case 1: { 
            int size_philtr = size_programmer;
            PROGRAMMER* philtr = new PROGRAMMER[size_philtr];

            for (int i = 0; i < size_programmer; i++)
                philtr[i] = { SPISOK[i] };
            std::cout << "Введите количество параметров фильтрации: ";
            int kolvo_pov;
            cin >> kolvo_pov;
            cin.ignore();
            while (kolvo_pov > SIZE_PARAMETRS) {
                std::cout << "\n\n ERROR:Недопустимое количество параметров \n\n";
                cin >> kolvo_pov;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_pov; i++)
                philtrf(philtr, size_philtr);
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_PARAMETRS; i++)//возвращение параметров в активное состояние
                parametrs[i].active = true;
            std::cout << "Результат сортировки: \n";
            Vivod(philtr, 0, size_philtr);
            break;
        }
        //Добавление
        case 2: {
            int kolvo_vvod;
            std::cout << "Введите количество сотрудников на добавление: ";
            cin >> kolvo_vvod;
            cin.ignore();
            for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_vvod; i++)
                ADD(SPISOK, size_programmer, i + 1);
            break;
        }
        //Удаление
        case 3: {
            int kolvo_delete;
            bool num_del = false;
            while (!num_del) {
                std::cout << "Введите количество сотрудников на удаление: ";
                cin >> kolvo_delete;
                cin.ignore();
                if (kolvo_delete > size_programmer)
                    std::cout << "ERROR:Недопустимое количество\n";
                else
                    num_del = true;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_delete; i++) {
                int* MB_DEL = NULL;
                MB_DEL = Search(SPISOK, size_programmer, 1);
                for (int j = 1; j < MB_DEL[0]; j++) {
                    std::cout << j<<")\n";
                    Vivod(SPISOK, MB_DEL[j], 1);
                }
                bool B_del{ false };
                while (!B_del) {
                    std::cout << "Какого из сотрудников удалить: ";
                    int num_del;
                    cin >> num_del;
                    if (!(num_del > MB_DEL[0]-1))
                        B_del = true;
                    else
                        std::cout << "ERROR:Выберите из предоставленных чисел\n";
                }
                cin.ignore();
                //Смещение удаляемого сотрудника в конец массива
                for (int i = MB_DEL[num_del]; i+1 < size_programmer; i++) {
                    PROGRAMMER temp = SPISOK[i];
                    SPISOK[i] = SPISOK[i + 1];
                    SPISOK[i + 1] = temp;
                }
                //Удаление сотрудника
                ReSize(SPISOK, Null_I, size_programmer, -1);
                std::cout << "Удаление произошло успешно\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        //Вывод
        case 4: {
            sort(SPISOK, SPISOK + size_programmer, compareProgrammers);
            Vivod(SPISOK, 0, size_programmer);
            break;
        }
        //Изменение
        case 5: {
            int* MB_IZM = NULL;
            MB_IZM = Search(SPISOK, size_programmer, 1);
            for (int j = 1; j < MB_IZM[0]; j++) {
                std::cout << j << ")\n";
                Vivod(SPISOK, MB_IZM[j], 1);
            }
            bool B_del{ false };
            while (!B_del) {
                std::cout << "Какого из сотрудников редактировать: ";
                int num_del;
                cin >> num_del;
                if (!(num_del > MB_IZM[0] - 1))
                    B_del = true;
                else
                    std::cout << "ERROR:Выберите из предоставленных чисел\n";
            }
            cin.ignore();
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_PARAMETRS; i++)
                std::cout << parametrs[i].num << ") " << parametrs[i].name << endl;
            int num_param;
            std::cout << "Введите параметр для изменения: \n";
            std::cin >> num_param;
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Введите новое значение: ";
            if (num_param == 2) {
                cin >> SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].DAY[0] >> SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].DAY[1] >> SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].DAY[2];
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else{
                string temp;
                getline(cin, temp);
                switch (num_param) {
                    case 1:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].NAME = temp;      break;
                    case 3:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].LANGUAGE = temp;  break;
                    case 4:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].TelNumber = temp; break;
                    case 5:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].Adress = temp;    break;
                    case 6:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].Email = temp;     break;
                    case 7:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].dolzhnost = temp; break;
                    case 8:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].status = temp;    break;
                    case 9:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].Project = temp;   break;
                    case 10:
                        SPISOK[MB_IZM[1]].Group = temp;     break;
                }
            }
            cout << "Изменения успешно сохранились.\n";
            break;
        }
        //Выход из программы
        case 6:

        sort(SPISOK, SPISOK + size_programmer, compareProgrammers);

        for (int i = 0; i < size_programmer; i++) {
            fSPISOKout.write((char*)&SPISOK[i], sizeof(PROGRAMMER));
        }
        
        break;  
        //Значения вне диапазона действий
        default:
            std::cout << "ERROR:Недопустимое действие\n";
            break;
        }

}
    fSPISOKout.close();
    return 0;
}
```